# find file then select for mutt attachment

Tags: bash, command-line, email-attachments, mutt

I am looking to streamline sending attachments with a fixed body message using the following bash script,

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "body of message" | mutt -s "subject" -a $(find /path/to/dir -type f -name "*$1*") -- $2 < /dev/null
```

however, sometimes the find command finds multiple files for attachment.  Is there a more interactive way of doing this?  For instance, if it finds files xyz.pdf, and xyz2.pdf that I can select one and then proceed with sending the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the output of `find` to the `select` command. It's a loop that lets you repeatedly select an item from a list of choices and run the body of the loop using
the just selected value.

```
select attachment in $(find /path/to/dir -type f -name "*$1*"); do
    echo "body of message" | mutt -s "subject" -a "$attachment" -- "$2" < /dev/null
    break   # To avoid prompting for another file to send
done
```

It's not ideal; it will break if it finds any files with whitespace in their names. You can be a little more careful about how you build the list of files (which is beyond the scope of this answer), then call the `select` command. For example:

```
# Two poorly named files and one terribly named file
possible=("file 1.txt" "file 2.txt" $'file\n3.txt')

select attachment in "${possible[@]}"; do
    echo "body of message" | ...
    break
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

function inter {
    typeset file array i=0
    while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
        array[i]=$file
        ((i+=1))
    done
    if (( i == 0 )); then
        echo "no file" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
    if (( i == 1 )); then
        echo "$array"
        return
    fi
    select file in "${array[@]}"; do
        if (( REPLY>=1 && REPLY<=i )); then
            break
        fi
    done </dev/tty
    echo "$file"
}

echo "body of message" | mutt -s "subject" -a "$(find /path/to/dir -type f -name "*$1*" -print0 | inter )" -- $2 < /dev/null
```